# How to remove specific parts of XML string with XSL

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I have following XML document:

```
    <mail>
        <body> Dear XY,
here are some random information as a placeholder.
==========================================
Fruit_Type: apple
Vagetable_Amount: potato
Animal_Counter: two dogs
==========================================

        </body>
    </mail>
```

And I need to shorten the body string to this form:

```
    <mail>
        <body>
            Fruit_Type: apple
            Vagetable_Amount: potato
            Animal_Counter: two dogs
        </body>
    </mail>
```

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use? You can tokenize the contents of the body and identify the lines between those starting/ending with e.g. `=`. It is not clear why you tag the question as XSL-FO while neither having FO input nor output.

Comment: I would use this first line in the XSL-file:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
I hope this helps

Comment: If you have to do this kind of thing a lot, it might be worth splitting it into two phases: first an up-conversion phase to add proper XML markup to the content in the body, and then a transformation to process the properly-marked-up document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '=====&#10;'), '&#10;=====')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To indent the result by a tab, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(substring-before(substring-after(., '=====&#10;'), '&#10;====='), '&#10;')">
            <xsl:text>&#10;&#9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

provided your processor supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: If I test your solution it works, but the result string is written in one line without linebreaks, do you maybe have a way to keep the structure of the string including the linebreaks?

Comment: I do get line breaks, so you must be doing something different - see the demo here:  https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3N7Dtjr

Comment: Oh yeah, the demo is working. Could it be that the linebreaks aren't kept because of my editor?

Comment: I don't know. Which editor are you using? I would suspect you are looking at the result in a browser.

Comment: Now it worked, but I recognized that there's a need for moving the whole body string with one tab space. That's necassary that the editor can read the string correct. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but it is not trivial in XSLT 1.0. Are you sure you cannot use a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 or higher?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 would be possible as well. Do you have a solution therefore?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now everything is working!